# How to change the chaptermark of bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, header-footer

In previously asked questions about changing the chaptermark in a bibliography, I couldn't get a solution for my problem. That is why I'm asking a new question.

I'm writing my thesis. The references span across multiple pages. On the top of the second (and further) page there is a header (that appears on every page where a new chapter does not begin). The header informs a reader about the current chapter he/she is reading. But in the references it says "Algemene conclusies", which is my last chapter. I would like this not to appear in the references and say "Bibliografie" instead.

Here is my code:

```
    \documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{report}

%\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=3cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=3.2cm,outer=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=1.5cm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{setspace} \onehalfspacing
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage[hang,small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight = 14pt
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}

%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}} 
%\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
%\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
%\fancyhead[HR]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headwidth}{16cm} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.3ex plus 0.3ex minus 0.3ex}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\makeatletter
\def\LigneVerticale{\vrule height 2cm depth 2cm\hspace{0.1cm}\relax}
\def\LignesVerticales{%
\let\LV\LigneVerticale\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV}
\def\GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre#1{%
\rlap{\vrule height 0.8cm width 1cm depth 0.2cm}%
\rlap{\hbox to 1cm{\hss\mbox{\white #1}\hss}}%
\vrule height 0pt width 1cm depth 0pt}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{\hbox{%
\huge
\LignesVerticales
\hspace{-0.5cm}%
\GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre{\thechapter}
\hspace{0.2cm}\hbox{#1}%
}\par\vskip 2cm}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{\hbox{%
\huge
\LignesVerticales
%\hspace{0.5cm}%
\hbox{#1}%
}\par\vskip 2cm}
```

This is the code in my document:

```
     %...
\chapter{Algemene conclusies}
    \input{Conclusie}
    \clearpage

    \clearpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografie}
    \input{Bibliografie}
```

And this is the code in the file bibliography:

```
\bibliography{bronnen}
   \bibliographystyle{agsm}%plainnat
```

Comment: in the file "Bibliografie", after the `\chapter*` line, add a line `\markboth{Bibliografie}{Bibliografie}` (uppercasing manually if appropriate to get a matching style).  the basic latex classes, including `report` don't provide automatic running head text for starred headings, which to my way of thinking is a misfeature.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately he now also changes the chaptermark of my last (empty) page of my previous chapter.

Comment: to avoid changing the heading on the blank last page of the prrvious chapter, put `\clearpage` just before the bibliography.  (i thought that `\chapter`, with or without star, did that automatically, but i didn't check.)

Comment: I don't think I understand. As you can see in my last piece of code I already have `\clearpage` before my bibliography starts. The `\markboth{Bibliografie}{Bibliografie}` I have put just after `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografie}`. In my file "Bibliografie" there are only 2 lines of code: `\bibliography{bronnen}
   \bibliographystyle{agsm}%plainnat` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're correct about `\clearpage`.  i've tried to process the (partial) file you've listed, but without some actual content, in particular for the bibliography (i plugged in some `lipsum` text to take up space), the result is what i expected when i made the suggestion.  so a real [minimum working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is needed.

Comment: Can you tell me where I need to put `\markboth{Bibliografie}{Bibliografie}` exactly? Because I don't have a `\chapter*` line...

Comment: it looks like your bibliography file is named `bronnen`.  if it follows the usual format of such files, `bronnen.bbl` will begin with a line `\begin{thebibliography}`.  place the `\markboth` immediately after that.  (it's been suggested that this discussion be moved to chat.  unfortunately, i'm working on a deadline, and can't manage that right now.)

Comment: No Problem. I'm so glad you were able to make time to help me. Thank you so mutch! It worked! Thank you. Good luck with your deadline.

Comment: One last question. Every time I run my file, the bbl file changes. So I need to put that line of code back each time. Is there anything I can do about that?

Comment: checking the definition of `thebibliography` in `report.cls`, it looks like the marks should actually be done automatically, if `\bibname` is defined correctly.  i have no idea why they are not.  so no, i can't even think of a way to redefine `thebibliography` to "do the right thing".  it looks like you're stuck with changing it every time.  sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you need, is to use `\markboth{}{Bibliografie}` for this. But you have to put it in the right place, and the right order of commands is:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografie}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}%plainnat
\bibliography{bronnen}
\markboth{Bibliografie}{}
```

Or if you really insist, then you place the three last lines in your file `Bibliografie.tex` in that order, and everything should work. If it doesn't, then don't use `\input`.

Comment: Thank you, but I must be doing something wrong... Now he gives one page with the title bibliografie, then nothing beneath, then on the next page again the chapter title bibliografie and then all my references.

Comment: Did you include a \clearpage or related command before?

Comment: No, I did use a \newpage

Comment: Edited the answer.