# How to keep a code in a bbl file?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

In my previously asked question about changing the chaptermark in a bibliography, I got a nice answer but unfortunately I need to place the code in my BBL file. This means I need to rewrite my code every run. Is there a solution for this, new, problem?

My first problem was:
I'm writing my thesis. The references span across multiple pages. On the top of the second (and further) page there is a header (that appears on every page where a new chapter does not begin). The header informs a reader about the current chapter he/she is reading. But in the references it says "Algemene conclusies", which is my last chapter. I would like this not to appear in the references and say "Bibliografie" instead.

This is my code for the preamble:

```
    \documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{report}

%\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=3cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=3.2cm,outer=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=1.5cm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{setspace} \onehalfspacing
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage[hang,small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight = 14pt
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}

%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}} 
%\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
%\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
%\fancyhead[HR]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headwidth}{16cm} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.3ex plus 0.3ex minus 0.3ex}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\makeatletter
\def\LigneVerticale{\vrule height 2cm depth 2cm\hspace{0.1cm}\relax}
\def\LignesVerticales{%
\let\LV\LigneVerticale\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV}
\def\GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre#1{%
\rlap{\vrule height 0.8cm width 1cm depth 0.2cm}%
\rlap{\hbox to 1cm{\hss\mbox{\white #1}\hss}}%
\vrule height 0pt width 1cm depth 0pt}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{\hbox{%
\huge
\LignesVerticales
\hspace{-0.5cm}%
\GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre{\thechapter}
\hspace{0.2cm}\hbox{#1}%
}\par\vskip 2cm}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{\hbox{%
\huge
\LignesVerticales
%\hspace{0.5cm}%
\hbox{#1}%
}\par\vskip 2cm}
```

This is my file:

```
\chapter{Algemene conclusies}
\input{Conclusie}
\newpage

\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografie}
\input{Bibliografie}
```

and this is the code in the file Bibliografie:

```
\bibliography{bronnen}
   \bibliographystyle{agsm}%plainnat
```

Comment: Maybe by setting `\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliografie}` and `addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliogafie}` ?

Comment: I have posted some code, I don't now if this helps. The `addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliogafie}` is already in my code. I 'll try to add `\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliografie}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others have pointed to the fact you don't change code in the `.bbl` file, and that you should be setting the `\bibname` and adding an entry for the contents.

Now the headings error lies with the marks not changing.  Internally `report` starts the bibliography with `\chapter*` which does not set the marks.  In the standard set-up the command `\@mkboth` is then issued with the `\bibname`, giving headings in the bibliography.  In your set-up this is not happening.  One fix is to simply add

```
\chaptermark{\bibname}
```

before your bibliography.

The other is the change your definition of `\@makeschapterhead` to

```
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{\hbox{%
\huge
\LignesVerticales
\hbox{#1}\chaptermark{#1}
}\par\vskip 2cm}
```

or to

```
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{\hbox{%
\huge
\LignesVerticales
#1
}\par\vskip 2cm}
```

The first one will change the marks to the current chapter name in all `\chapter*` cases and  produce running heads in line with your other chapters.  The other will revert to standard `report` behaivour i.e., in bibliography left and right heads displaying `\bibname`, and no resetting of header names at ordinary `\chapter*`.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question on how to keep code in a bbl file: you don't. It's a temporary file used to generate the bibliography from. If you need to put code in that file, your solution isn't a solution.

Regarding your problem: See the answer on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115801/how-to-change-the-chaptermark-of-bibliography/115927#115927)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the name of the bibliography by using `\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliografie}`.

Just please bear in mind that if you are using `hyperref`, you should also include:

```
\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliografie}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografie}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{bronnen}
```

*There is no need to `\input` a file named "Bibliografie", you can call it directly with the command `\bibliography{nameofyourfile}`.

Comment: I tries to put your code instead of mine (`\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografie}
\input{Bibliografie}`) but unfortunatly it still doesn't give what I want. It still gives "algemene conclusies" on the left side page in the chaptermark...

Comment: Try adding `\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}` at the beginning of my code

Comment: @MusLiselot Did it work?

Comment: Sorry, my computer was still running, it's a big file. No, unfortunatly it doesn't work.

Comment: @MusLiselot Try running it a couple of times.  It should really work. (I updated my answer to include the `\newpage` part)

Comment: No, I'm sorry, it still doesn't work ... Thank you for all your effort by the way!

Comment: @MusLiselot The problem is in the way you define the top header.  I've run this without your definition and works just fine.  For example, try replacing everything inside the `makeatletter` for  \lhead[\fancyplain{}{\rm\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\sl\rightmark}}
  \chead{}
  \rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\rm\thepage}}
  \lfoot{}
  \cfoot{\fancyplain{\rm\thepage}{}}
  \rfoot{}

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you, but on the other hand I lose my style of my chapters. Before is was |||| 1 blabla. Now it's the standard of latex.

Comment: @MusLiselot Yes, I know... I'm sorry I can't help you with that.  I'm not very good at playing with custom-made stuff.  Maybe you should ask it as a separate question.